# Silverlight Domain Service Help

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services

I have created a Silverlight Business app, and have created a Domain Service within the app.web project.

I have created a method inside the DomainService class:

```
public String reHi()
    {
        return "HI";
    }
```

Inside my client, Silverlight page I had set the namepsace

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
```

I then included the following code to get the context:

```
Repas.Web.RepasContext t = new Repas.Web.RepasContext();
MessageBox.Show(t.reHi());
```

The project then fails to build with the error:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert
>   from
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation'
>   to 'string'

I then added a toString to the code to see what it will output but I get:

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation`1[System.String]

Can someone help me to get the output ("Hi") that I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All service calls to Silverlight are asynchronous; in other words, you don't get the response back immediately.  Rather, you must set up an event handler for the *completion* of the call.  I don't know your service definition, but it may look something like this:

```
var operation = t.reHi();
operation.Completed += (s, e) => {
    MessageBox.Show(operation.Value);
};
```

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Using your code didn't work, there is not operation.Result, errors mainly telling me that it is inaccessible due to it's protection level

Comment: Now that's working, seems like an implementation I can work with. So I will need to follow this structure for all service calls then am I right? Thanks again